# How long can it take to send a message of 200 Byte in an IEEE 802.15.4 beacon enabled network?

Tags: iot

How long can it take to send a message of 200 Byte in an IEEE 802.15.4 beacon enabled network?

I am not clear with this question and how to calculate this time.

I have tried to find the articles about `IEEE 802.15.4.`

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are three kinds of data rates of IEEE 802.15.4. They are 250 kbps, 40 kbps, and 20 kbps. The time vary among rates. Calculation formula is

```
Time(s) = Data(bits) / Rate(bps)
```

For example, if the rate is 20 kbps, the data(message) is 200 Bytes, so the time is

```
(200*8)/(20*1000)=0.08s=80ms
```

If you use 250kbps the time is `6.4ms`.

Note: Time calculated here is the time of transmitting message in the air. Generally, actual time is longer because processing time does not take into account here.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: @Wuu, you can vote this up or mark as answer if you find the answer useful.